# php disable button after onclick but skipped the rest process

Tags: php

I want to disable a button after the button onclick and then enable the other one .

```
echo '<input type="text" id="txtbox1" name="tb1" value="'.$value.'" />';
echo '<input type="submit" id="btn1" name = "btnstart" value="START" onClick="this.disabled=true;"/><input type="submit" id="btn2" name = "btnend" value="End" onClick="this.disabled=true;"/>';
```

In this case, i can only disable the button but the rest of the process skipped. I cannot update the input textbox value.

Also, How can i disable the btn2 the before onclick btn1?

```
$value= $_POST['tb1']; 
echo '<form name="f1" method="POST" action="">';
echo '<input type="text" id="txtbox1" name="tb1" value="'.$value.'" />';
echo '<input type="submit" id="btn1" name = "btnstart" value="START" onClick="this.disabled=true;"/><input type="submit" id="btn2" name = "btnend" value="End" onClick="this.disabled=true;"/>';
echo '</form>';
echo '</td>';

if ( isset( $_POST['tb1'] ) ) {
$new = $value *12;
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want?at first both buttons should be enabled then after clinking on `btn1` it should be disabled and `btn2` should be enabled?

Comment: I want to enable the btn1 and disable btn2 when the page loaded. After clicking btn1 , btn1 disable and then enable btn2.
After clicking btn2, btn2 disable also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="submit" id="btn1" name = "btnstart" value="START" onClick="document.getElementById('btn2').disabled=false;this.disabled=true;"/>
<input type="submit" id="btn2" name = "btnend" value="End" onClick="this.disabled=true;" disabled/>
```

Working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8AHYa/)

Comment: I did it thank you. but I cant get the textbox value `if(isset($_POST['btnstart']` , echo null .Can u help me?

Comment: If it is what you wanted please accept the answer :) show the full code where you want to get the textbox value.

Comment: in `$_POST` the value is the name of the textbox which you want. In your case it will be `$_POST['tb1']`

Comment: I can send you the full code in pic , are u interested in it ?

Comment: remove `$value= $_POST['tb1'];` from top and place it inside your if statement before calculating `$new`.

Comment: it works fine when `<input type="submit" id="btn1" name = "btnstart'.$vid.'" value="START"/>` . however when i changed into `<input type="submit" id="btn1" name = "btnstart'.$vid.'" value="START" onClick="document.getElementById(\'btn2\').disabled=false;this.disabled=true;` i cannot get the value

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this,

**How can i disable the btn2 at the before onclick btn1?**

Added `onClick="document.getElementById(\'btn2\').disabled=true;this.disabled=true;"`

```
    echo '<input type="text" id="txtbox1" name="tb1" value="'.$value.'" />';
    echo '<input type="submit" id="btn1" name = "btnstart" value="START" onClick="document.getElementById(\'btn2\').disabled=true;this.disabled=true;"/>
    <input type="submit" id="btn2" name = "btnend" value="End" onClick="this.disabled=true;"/>';
```

Comment: I did it thank you. but I cant get the textbox value if(isset($_POST['btnstart'] , echo null .Can u help me?

Comment: to get textbox value `echo $_POST['tb1'];`

Answer (score 0):

try jquery

first load the html with submit button 2 disabled

```
echo '<input type="text" id="txtbox1" name="tb1" value="" />';
echo '<input type="submit" id="btn1" name = "btnstart" value="START" /><input type="submit" id="btn2" name = "btnend" value="End" disabled="disabled" />';
```

then using jquery

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("input[type='submit']").click(function(){

          $("input[type='submit']").prop('disabled',false);
          $(this).prop('disabled',true);
      });
   });
```

disable the clicked submit button and enable other submit button

Answer (score -1):

I placed an example in jQuery. jQuery is much easier then normal Javascript. Dont forget that jQuery is still javascript but then with functions that are already named to do their function:

```
.click() //When clicked
.next() //Next element/attribute
.mouseenter //When hover
.text() //Set the text

$('#mydiv').text('Contains this text');
```

Do the codecadamy.com training, its very helpfull, easy to follow and very quick.

I placed an example in jQuery for you:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27P3c/)

Comment: No need to do so much coding when it can be done in a single line. :)

Comment: Its not about one line, what im saying is using jQuery is much easier. So if a starter needs something that gets done immediatly, learning jQuery is easier then learning JS ;)